# Why does this regex for emails not work

Tags: php, regex, email

I'm trying to make a regex to match email addresses, like any of these:

```
example@website.com
first.last@website.org
joe87_smith@web.net
```

I've written this regex:

```
$pattern = "/[\-\.\_a-z0-9]+(\@){1}[\-\.\_a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.){1}[\-a-z0-9]+/i";
```

and here is some code that I am using to test it:

```
$str = "test_last@test.com was the email address associated with another one, another.test@other.org";
$pattern = "/[\-\.\_a-z0-9]+(\@){1}[\-\.\_a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.){1}[\-a-z0-9]+/i";
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

(The text between the emails is filler)
It's supposed to do as follows:

1. Check for a username that can include one or more periods, dashes, underscores, or alphanumeric characters.
2. Check for one and only one (required) "@" sign.
3. Check for a domain or any number of subdomains (alphanumeric + periods + dashes)
4. Check for a period followed by alphanumeric or dash characters.

When I test the code above, I get this output:

```
array(3) {
    [0] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(22) "test_last@test.com was"
        [1] => string(22) "another.test@other.org"
    }
    [1] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1) "@"
        [1] => string(1) "@"
    }
    [2] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1) " "
        [1] => string(1) "r"
    }
 }
```

Why is it matching so many other characters, such as single @ signs and the letter "r"?
Why does the very first email contain the word was? I never tested for spaces to my knowledge...

Comment: There's lots of email addresses that aren't anything like those.

Comment: `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` to the rescue :)

Comment: First off Preg_match will match based on groups such as: `(\@)`

Comment: The other results that are returned (matches[1] and matches[2]) are the backreferences returned due to use of parenthesis. The result in matches[0] is the list of complete regex matches.

Comment: Infact your pasted results are odd because this is what I get: `Array
(
    [0] => test_last@test.com
    [1] => @
    [2] => .
)`

Comment: @Sammaye Either way there are extraneous results.

Comment: I get extraneous results vbecause of the groups you are using. If you took out the groups my preg_match will find only the email.

Comment: @KaranPunamiya Is there are difference between `(\@)` and `[\@]`? It doesn't matter to me. I know that one is a group and the other a char class, but when using one char does it matter?

Comment: So I use: `/[\-\.\_a-z0-9]+[\@]{1}[\-\.\_a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.]{1}[\-a-z0-9]+/` and it returns: `Array
(
    [0] => test_last@test.com
)`

Comment: I agree, it was due to the use of parentheses. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question from the comments. The problem was using groups within regex which means that `preg_match_all` was matching on those groups separately as well.

Changing the regex to:

```
/[\-\.\_a-z0-9]+[\@]{1}[\-\.\_a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.]{1}[\-a-z0-9]+/
```

Returned:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => test_last@test.com
            [1] => another.test@other.org
        )

)
```

Using the OPs test text.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has built in filters to check for things like e-mail validity now. More specifically, you might want to look into [filter_var()](http://ca.php.net/filter_var) and the [FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) filter.

Sample usage:

```
$valid_email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if($valid_email)
        echo "Hooray!";
```

All three of your sample e-mail addresses should return the "hooray!"

Comment: Note: If you are looking for complete domains only within emails then validate_email will also validate incomplete domains such as `example@example`. Even though this is a valid email is might be undesired behaviour within most web apps.

Answer (score 0):

Validating email addresses (with regexp and otherwise) is problematic; see here: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).